# How to GroupJoin from flat XDocument?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have an XDocument with a fragment that resembles:

> ```
> <Data>
>     <Row Id="0" ParentId="-1">
>         <!-- stuff -->
>     </Row>
>     <Row Id="1" ParentId="0">
>         <!-- stuff -->
>     </Row>
>     <Row Id="2" ParentId="0">
>         <!-- stuff -->
>     </Row>
>     <Row Id="3" ParentId="-1">
>         <!-- stuff -->
>     </Row>
>     <Row Id="4" ParentId="3">
>         <!-- stuff -->
>     </Row>
> </Data>
> ```

Assume nesting is limited to the example above.
I want to create a data structure - `IDictionary<Parent, List<Child>>`. I can't seem to get anything to join correctly. What I have to this point is:

```
// get lists of data nodes
List<XElement> pRows = xData.Elements(XName.Get("Row"))
                            .Where(e => e.Attribute(XParentId).Value == "-1")
                            .Select(e => e)
                            .ToList();
List<XElement> cRows = xData.Elements(XName.Get("Row"))
                            .Where(e => e.Attribute(XParentId).Value != "-1")
                            .Select(e => e)
                            .ToList();

var dataSets = pRows.GroupJoin(cRows,
                               p => p,
                               c => c.Attribute(XParentId).Value,
                               (p, children) => new {
                                 ParentID = p.Attribute(XId).Value,
                                 Children = children.Select(c => c)
                               });
```

The compiler is complaining:

> The type arguments for method 
>   'System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupJoin(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Func, System.Func,
>   System.Func,TResult>)'
>   cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments
>   explicitly.

I followed a sample from [MSDN using the GroupJoin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534297.aspx). I didn't want to use 2 lists - I'd prefer to use a single list of `List<XElement>` containing all the rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the 2 list approach is cleaner, except I would avoid calling `ToList()` until the final step or when the list is really needed. You could turn it into one statement, but it would be long and harder to follow.

To fix your query, you need to change the outer key selector for `pRows` from `p => p` to `p => p.Attribute(XId).Value`, which is the actual ID. Currently it selects the entire element, which cannot be compared to `c => c.Attribute(XParentId).Value` since they are different types. The updated query would be:

```
var dataSets = pRows.GroupJoin(cRows,
                               p => p.Attribute(XId).Value,
                               c => c.Attribute(XParentId).Value,
                               (p, children) => new {
                                 ParentID = p.Attribute(XId).Value,
                                 Children = children.Select(c => c)
                               });
```

To avoid using 2 lists you could modify the query above and replace `pRows` and `cRows` with their respective queries, but that makes it long and harder on the eyes. In this particular case I prefer expressing the `GroupJoin` using query syntax since it is much easier to read than the fluent syntax:

```
var query = from root in xData.Elements("Row").Where(e => e.Attribute("ParentId").Value == "-1")
            join child in xData.Elements("Row").Where(e => e.Attribute("ParentId").Value != "-1")
            on root.Attribute("Id").Value equals child.Attribute("ParentId").Value
            into rootChild
            select new 
            {
                ParentId = root.Attribute("Id").Value,
                Children = rootChild.Select(o => o)
            };

var dict = query.ToDictionary(o => o.ParentId, o => o.Children.ToList());
```

Should your real problem have more nesting, LINQ probably won't be the ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

First, to make your code compile you might want to replace the parameter `p => p` in the `GroupJoin` with `p => p.Attribute(XId).Value` which selects the key for comparison.

As a result you will get an IEnumerable with objects

- ParentID=0, `IEnumerable<XElement>` { Row Id=1, Row Id=2 }
- ParentID=3, `IEnumerable<XElement>` { Row Id=4 }

Of course, you can also change the `.Select(c => c)` to return a `List<string>` with just the IDs (`.Select(c => c.Attribute(XId).Value).ToList()`), but you are still missing **ParentID=-1** and you don't have a dictionary.

If you want to include the ParentID=-1 and also get a `Dictionary<string,List<string>>` then you might want to try this (as a point to start from), which uses a different approach:

```
// get all ParentIds
var allParentIds = xData.Elements(XName.Get("Row"))
                        .Select(e => e.Attribute(XParentId).Value)
                        .Distinct();
// then use them to get all Ids where the ParentId is in the "list" of all ParentIds
var parentIdsAndChilds = from givenIds
                         in allParentIds
                         select new {
                             Id = givenIds,
                             Childs = xData.Elements(XName.Get("Row")).Where(e => e.Attribute(XParentId).Value == givenIds).Select(e => e.Attribute(XId).Value).ToList()
                         };
// if needed, convert it to a Dictionary
Dictionary<string, List<string>> dict = parentIdsAndChilds.ToDictionary(k => k.Id, v => v.Childs);
```

I hope this helps, or maybe provides a starting point for further research.

One side note: as you might know, LINQ uses *deferred execution* so you might not want to call `ToList()` on every step to save execution time (depending on the overall amount of data, it might be a good idea to use `ToList()` anyway now and then because it might save memory during processing, but this depends on the real data).